# Edit table error in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I use `SQL server 2008` and I have created some tables. I want to edit some of them, but `SSMS` does not let me and will receive error!

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: can you post the error message that you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving changes after table edit in SQL Server Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969096/saving-changes-after-table-edit-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside SSMS go to menu:

```
tool -> options -> designers
```

Uncheck `prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`

Image:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe you connected that question to that response... If that really is the problem you sir are a genius.

Or you've seen this issue before :)

Comment: hehe.  saw that on a friends machine recently.

Comment: He seen that problem before @Mike M. :). I have similar issue.