# Altering a column to be nullable

Tags: sql

I want to alter a table column to be nullable. I have used:

```
ALTER TABLE Merchant_Pending_Functions Modify NumberOfLocations NULL
```

This gives an error at `Modify`. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Please post the error message in future

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tag as it looks like this has become a general free for all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say more about what isn't working. Do you see an error message? If so, what is it? It is not producing the expected output? If not, what output do you see and what output do you expect?

Answer (score 758, accepted):

Assuming `SQL Server` (based on your previous questions):

```
ALTER TABLE Merchant_Pending_Functions ALTER COLUMN NumberOfLocations INT NULL
```

Replace `INT` with your actual datatype.

Comment: Tried to use the table "Design" utility in SSMS to change a bit column from NOT NULL to NULL. I got an error that indicated that the table needed to be dropped and re-created. Whoa! This ALTER TABLE syntax worked and was much easier than dropping and re-creating a table to make a single column nullable.

Comment: @JohnH Most attempts to modify a table with the Designer result in that warning. You can remedy that by changing the options in SSMS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969096/saving-changes-after-table-edit-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: @JLRishe It's worth noting that it's not advisable to remove that warning unless someone really knows the consequences of the designer dropping/recreating a table behind-the-scenes. It has the potential to bite.

Answer (score 90):

In PostgreSQL it is:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN columnName DROP NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 76):

If this was MySQL syntax, the type would have been missing, as some other responses point out.
Correct MySQL syntax would have been:

```
ALTER TABLE Merchant_Pending_Functions MODIFY NumberOfLocations INT NULL
```

Posting here for clarity to MySQL users.

Answer (score 49):

for Oracle Database 10g users:

```
alter table mytable modify(mycolumn null);
```

You get "ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option" when you try otherwise

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn DROP NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Cool, you don't have to specify the data-type, just "null" to make it nullable.

Answer (score 13):

For SQL Server or TSQL

```
ALTER TABLE Complaint.HelplineReturn ALTER COLUMN IsDisposed BIT NULL
```

Answer (score 8):

Although I don't know what RDBMS you are using, you probably need to give the whole column specification, not just say that you now want it to be nullable. For example, if it's currently `INT NOT NULL`, you should issue `ALTER TABLE Merchant_Pending_Functions Modify NumberOfLocations INT`.

Comment: This is a correct and descriptive answer, so just clarifying if `Null` | `NOT NULL` is not specified, the column will be nullable.

Answer (score 4):

As others have observed, the precise syntax for the command varies across different flavours of DBMS.  The syntax you use works in Oracle:

```
SQL> desc MACAddresses
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COMPUTER                                           NUMBER
 MACADDRESS                                         VARCHAR2(12)
 CORRECTED_MACADDRESS                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(17)

SQL> alter table MACAddresses
  2       modify corrected_MACAddress null
  3  /

Table altered.

SQL> desc MACAddresses
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COMPUTER                                           NUMBER
 MACADDRESS                                         VARCHAR2(12)
 CORRECTED_MACADDRESS                               VARCHAR2(17)

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle

> `ALTER TABLE Merchant_Pending_Functions MODIFY([column]  NOT NULL);`

Comment: Does this answer bring anything new with respect to @IgorS's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664940/8516269)? And what does `SQL_SCRIPT` stand for?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what SQL Engine you are using, in Sybase your command works fine:

```
ALTER TABLE Merchant_Pending_Functions 
Modify NumberOfLocations NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

For HSQLDB:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN columnName SET NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE Merchant_Pending_Functions MODIFY COLUMN `NumberOfLocations` INT null;
```

This will work for you.

If you want to change a not null column to allow null, no need to include not null clause. Because default columns get not null.

```
ALTER TABLE Merchant_Pending_Functions MODIFY COLUMN `NumberOfLocations` INT;
```

Answer (score 1):

### SQLite

The [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) command is a bit special. There is no possibility to modify a column. You have to create a new column, migrate the data, and then drop the column:

```
-- 1. First rename
ALTER TABLE
    Merchant_Pending_Functions
RENAME COLUMN
    NumberOfLocations
TO
   NumberOfLocations_old

-- 2. Create new column
ALTER TABLE
    Merchant_Pending_Functions
ADD COLUMN
    NumberOfLocations INT NULL

-- 3. Migrate data - you need to write code for that
-- 4. Drop the old column
ALTER TABLE
    Merchant_Pending_Functions
DROP COLUMN
    NumberOfLocations_old
```

Comment: Thanks Dr Hipp.  SQLite is unusual as the schema is stored character for character as the user entered it, including all the white space.  This is claimed as an advantage as it takes less storage.  But makes DDL tasks difficult.  Also a real pain for DBAs.

Comment: What do you mean with "Dr Hipp"?

Comment: Dr Richard Hipp wrote SQLite. And made the world a better place.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the data_type of the column to modify.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE NULL;
```

Comment: Please add code type notation for your answer and some describe about this