# Delete the column for the particular value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using Sql Server 2005

Table1

```
ID Name Value

001 Rajesh 90
002 Suresh 100
003 Mahesh 200
004 Virat 400
...
```

I want to delete the value from the table1 for the particular id

Tried Query

```
Delete value from table1 where id = '001'
```

The above query is not working.

How to make a delete query for delete the particular column

Need Query Help

Comment: Try delete from table1 where id = '001'

Comment: what's the type of ID? In what sense is your delete not working? Is it giving an error? Is it giving no errors but not deleting the row?

Comment: @Verrigo: I don't think that's what he wants. I don't think he wants to delete the entire row.

Comment: Mark, yeah, you are right, i don't think he wants that. Anyway, this question should be resolved, there are two answers and yours deals with both situations:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least two errors with your statement:

- The word `table` will give a syntax error because it is a reserved word. You need to specify the table name of the specific table you wish to delete from.
- Also you cannot write `DELETE value FROM`. It's just `DELETE FROM`. And note that it deletes the **entire row**, not just a single value.

A correct delete statement would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE id = '001'
```

However if you want to change a single value to NULL you should use an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE table1
SET value = NULL
WHERE id = '001'
```

Of course this assumes that the column is nullable. If not, you'll have to fix that first. See this question for details:

- [Altering a column to be nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556890/altering-a-column-to-be-nullable)

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to set the value to null

```
update Table1 set value=NULL where id='001'
```