# 'JPA/Hibernate: Change primitive Datatype(double) to Wrapper (Double)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to change primitiv (double) to Wrapper (Double) in JPA.
Data already exists in Database with the primitive data type (double).

```
Current Status:
private double item;

What i want:
private Double item;
```

If i change double to Double i get an error : ---> Column 'item' cannot be null.
Its because primitiv Datatypes does not except null. But before i have changed my Model to the Wrapper Double.

So i think JPA does not update Datatable Schema, to allow null for 'item'.

I have already set update property for Hibernate.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

Any Idea how to deal with this ?

Comment: how important is your data? it's dummy data ? If it's a dummy data than you can simply use `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />` and re run the server after than change to `update`.

Comment: Its production data

Comment: How to deal with it ? Do a manual transform on the table structure so that you change the column to be "NULL". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556890/altering-a-column-to-be-nullable

Comment: `ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myColumn {DataType} NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add **nullable = true** to your item column, this will allow null value and regenerate your schema
ex:

```
@Column(name = "ITEM", nullable=true)  
private Double item;
```

Or

just initialize your wrapper type with 0