# Query for altering column to be nullabe not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make column called `start_date_data_id` to be nullable.

I found this answer([Altering a column to be nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556890/altering-a-column-to-be-nullable/3556942)) and tried to do it on described way.

**Description of that column:** (`| start_date_data_id| bigint(20)| NO | MUL | NULL |   |`).

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE attenddb.company_group_user_settings
    ALTER COLUMN start_date_data_id bigint(20) NULL;
```

Error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'bigint(20) NULL' at line 1

Can someone tell me why is it not working?

Comment: @Ronald Aaronson I tried, but the same error happened.

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you referenced is for ms sql server (it says so). Had you scrolled down a little bit in the answers, you would have found the mysql specific answer as well. Anyway, linked in another question that is mysql specific only, to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE attenddb.company_group_user_settings
MODIFY start_date_data_id bigint(20) NULL;
```

Comment: This is working, thank you.

Comment: Please accept it if this is the solution

Comment: I will, but need to wait 5 more minutes.

Comment: The reason why your code didnt work is because you are using SQL Server syntax whereas MySQL uses a different syntax.