# Catastrophic failure (Exception from(E_UNEXPECTED)) (SQLEditors)) after modifying column type

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, after I have modified column type from varchar to int I tried to update the table but it throw the following error

> Saving changes is not permitted. The change you have made requires the
> following table to be dropped and re-created. You have either made
> changes to a table that can't be recreated or enabled the option
> prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created. (list of 3 tables have a relation with this table as fk)

I tried to fix it by **Tools >> Options >> Designers and uncheck “Prevent Saving changes that require table re-creation”**
from this question

[Sql Server 'Saving changes is not permitted' error ► Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810425/sql-server-saving-changes-is-not-permitted-error-prevent-saving-changes-that)

then the update not throw any error but It throw the following error when open table design

> Catastrophic failure (Exception from(E_UNEXPECTED)) (SQLEditors))
> after modifying column type

I tried this but also the same error

> RegSvr32 msxml3.dll
>
> RegSvr32 msxml6.dll

Comment: before you changed column type did you confirm that all the data in the column is a valid data type for the new column?  Meaning you dont have letters in a filed you are trying to convert to INT?  Another way to do this is to create a new column in the table with the correct datatype, then update the new column with the values from the old column, then drop the old column, and finally rename the new column to what the old columns name was

Comment: @Brad yes all values is integer (1,2,3..) ,  Another way to do this is to create a new ... (how to do that the table design not opened)

Comment: Not clear on what your saying/asking?  The table design not opened?

Comment: @Brad when I tried to open table design it throw the second error in my question

Comment: Ok, is there anyway you can revert your changes back to what they were before you made any changes?  This may fix the current error then you can look at doing the process/data change a diffderent way

Comment: but select top 1000 rows it open the table data correctly

Comment: Without using the UI interface you can alter a table by typing ALTER TableName ADD COLUMNNAME DataType

Comment: I would revert your changes back and make sure everything is worknig/stable as it was before you made your changes.  Then I can help develope a solution

Comment: thanks @Brad after restart the studio the changes has removed then I have applied your device for alter table . can you please write that as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per comments updating here:

Revert back the changes to what they were before the error and work on a differnt solution to fix the problem.

One alternative is:

1. Create new column in table that you want the data to be inserted into/converted to
2. Update that new column from the existing column you have the data in you are trying to convert from.
3. Verify the data in the new column is correct/works good.
4. Drop the old column.
5. Rename the new column to the old columns name.