# Does identity column start at the specified seed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

Referring to the image attached below which is from SQL Server Management Studio, I have a table with records in it already, and the last record has an `id of 7`. I wish to have this column auto increment as the primary key (as it did before some unknown stuff-up), obviously with the next record having an `id of 8`.

[image]

Will specifying the seed as 7 mean the next record will be given an id of 7? Or will it be (7 + incrementValue) giving 8?

Comment: @marc_s  my current circumstances don't allow me to experiment with the database and data as you suggest. And I had to do it ASAP, no time to work with a copy/dummy table. Either way, I ended up going with instinct before anyone answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server is intelligent enough, any value you give from 1 to 8 it will start from 8 only.

For example if you give the `Identity Seed` as 1, and insert a record to the table, SQL will calculate the new `Identity` as 8 only.

If you specify > 8 in that case only it will consider the seed value.

**Note:** When you are using `SSMS` to achieve this, internally table will be dropped and a new table will be created  with proper identity.

If you want to do this using an sql query, you have to follow the instruction mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your table is large,then you have to query to find max id

Simply do this,

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TableName', RESEED, 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think SQL Server will force you to recreate the table with the new identity, and you will have to shift your data into that table where it will start at 1 and increment by 1.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. You can modify a table as is. But as PSK mentioned, a new table is created under the covers

Comment: Interesting, I get a message that says:  Saving changes is not permitted.  The changes you have made require the following tables to be dropped and re-created.   You have either made changes to a table that can't be re-created or enabled the option Prevent saving changes to require the table to be re-created.

Comment: You can find the override for that error here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6810442/870565