# Permission to save database

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Saving changes after table edit in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969096/saving-changes-after-table-edit-in-sql-server-management-studio)

I need to make changes in a already made database, but SQL is refusing my request. Something about preventing changes that require the table to be re-created??

What to do?

Comment: We need to see the error message to help us better understand your problem.

Comment: What changes? What errors? Show us your code and error messages.

Comment: Saving changes is not permitted. The changes you have made require the following tables to be dropped and re-created. You have either made changes to a table that can´t be re-created or enabled the option Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created.

Comment: you need to add a bounty to donate points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an option in sql server management studio. It is not a permission issue.

[To change this option, on the Tools menu, click Options, expand Designers, and then click Table and Database Designers. Select or clear the Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created check box.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895146.aspx)

Comment: Sorry 2 bother u sir. Can i ask u another question or shall I write again?

Comment: Best to ask another question if it is a separate problem. You can add a link to this 1 if it is related.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've run into the following error when trying to alter a table structure via SSMS...

[image]

This is just a safety precaution in SSMS...read [this article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2009/saving-changes-not-permitted/) to learn how to disable it.  Or better yet, manually script out the DDL changes in TSQL and add in some error-handling and reverse-changes logic.