# SSMS - scripting data on change

Tags: sql, ssms

Does anyone know of a way of scripting the data changes made via SSMS, e.g. update a table row and it shows the update SQL for that change, likewise for inserts & deletes?

I'm aware of being able to script out the entire changes using publishing wizard or using redgate software & I know you can switch on scripting for schema changes. However, I'm looking for something along the lines of: I do something in SSMS and I get a instant SQL statement telling me what I've done. I remember SQLYog doing something like this for MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for the same thing on SO with no luck, so clicked a few buttons in SSMS and found this:

[image]

"Generate Change Script" can be clicked after you've made changes in the SSMS designer. Upon clicking this button, a dialog appears that lets you view the SQL required to be run on your database for those changes.

If you check "Automatically generate change script on every save", then the same dialog will appear each time you click the save button.

You'll note that sometimes SSMS generates some ridiculously long SQL statements for seemingly simple changes. Unfortunately, even simple things like reordering/renaming columns cannot be expressed in standard SQL DDL statement - [all SSMS can do is drop and recreate the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969096/saving-changes-after-table-edit-in-sql-server-management-studio).